# The Response content must be a string or object implementing __toString(), “boolean”

Tags: laravel, boolean, file-get-contents, tostring

I have an API , i want to get this API details using file_get_contents using laravel code. But i getting this error "The Response content must be a string or object implementing __toString(), "boolean" given."
Here is my code,

```
$context = stream_context_create(array(
    'http' => array(
        'header'  => "Authorization: Basic " . base64_encode("$username:$password") 
    )
));

$ss =  @file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
return $ss;
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: what you want in return? if you want success message then return => return 'success'

Comment: what API returns

Comment: depend on your api requirement.

Answer (score 0):

you must return string:

```
if($ss)
   return 'success';
```

Answer (score 0):

Your error message says you're returning a boolean, which means your call to `file_get_contents()` is returning `false`, which means the call failed.

You need something like:

```
$ss =  @file_get_contents($url, false, $context);

if ($ss === false) {
    return 'file_get_contents failed.';
}

return $ss;
```

If you want to know why your `file_get_contents()` failed, you'll need to remove the `@` sign to stop suppressing the error.

Comment: i had removed the @sign and got error as 'failed to open stream: Connection refused.'. Is this problem with my server ?